# How to compare esp in masm x86?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I have a function in MASM x86 without a prologue. I want to compare an argument on the stack that was passed to the function.

```
.MODEL flat
extern x:dword

foo proc
cmp esp+4, x
...
foo endp
```

I've tried `DWORD PTR [esp+4],x` as well but that doesn't work either. I don't want to mess with popping from the stack or anything else because this is just a forwarding function. My question is basically why can't I make a comparison directly with an arg on the stack against a global variable? If it's impossible please tell me a different way to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x86 dooesn't support direct comparison of two memory locations. You need to move one of them into a register (preferably `eax`) first and then compare using the register:

```
MOV EAX, x
CMP DWORD PTR [ESP + 4], EAX
```

Comment: I'm not sure if he wants to compare [esp+4] to the word stored at address x or to the address of x. The last instruction would be "cmpl $x, 4(%esp)" in AT&T syntax. It would be one instruction (encoded as 81 7c 24 04 xx xx xx xx) and not need an additional register - unfortunately I do not know NTASM's syntax. MAYBE it would be "cmp dword ptr [esp+4], offset x"...

Comment: @MartinRosenau Yup, if he wanted to compare with the address of `x` he surely would have written `offset x` or something with the `lea` instruction.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't really understand what you mean. `DWORD PTR [esp + 4]` obtains the `DWORD` at `esp + 4`, i.e. indirection **is** provided. Or do you mean yet another level of indirection?